# datatable() method is not accessible from ajax callback method:

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-callback

In my ajax response i am getting HTML content and i wanted to apply datatable on that content(table inside that content). Sometimes it works sometimes not (says that datatable is not a function).

Here is my code:

```
sendAjax: function(params,dataTableParams){
    $('#thrbr').removeClass("dispNn");
    $("#summaryResultDiv").empty();
    $.ajax({
        url : ajaxURL,
        type : 'post',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : JSON.stringify(params),
        context : document.body
    }).done(function(html, textStatus, request) {
        $('#thrbr').addClass("dispNn");
        if(html.length>0){
            $("#summaryResultDiv").html(html);
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(document).height()
            },
            100);
            setInterval($("#summaryResult").dataTable(dataTableParams),200);

        }
    }

});
```

Any inputs? whats going wrong here? I have checked with console.log() dataTable() method is available on load time but not in context of ajax call back.

Comment: your usage of setInterval is incorrect. It expects a function or a string, you gave it an object.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your quick reply. I tried without setInterval also //$("#summaryResult").dataTable(dataTableParams); but the problem was same.

Comment: The only way that error can happen is if `$("#summaryResultDiv").html(html);` is including another copy of jquery, which overwrites the one that has your datatable plugin.

Comment: I have removed all JS code from html (getting in response), still no luck. Does this means ajax callback method does not have access to outside methods?

Comment: Should #summaryResult be #summaryResultDiv

Comment: @Alex: #summaryResult is a table id which coming into html response. And problem here with dataTable() method which shows not available in callback method.

Comment: I see nothing that would cause your ajax callback closure to not have access to the same `$` unless it's being overridden.